# Java Multicast receiver not working

Tags: java, multicast

I want to capture packets from one Multicast Group and port. First I checked using tcpdump command that data gets captured or not.

**Command -**

```
tcpdump -i <interface name> dst <multicast ip>
```

I created one program in java which will join this multicast group and prints the data on console.

**receiver -**

```
public class MulticastClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(<port number here>);
        //socket.setInterface(InetAddress.getByName("<local interface ip address>")); // This line makes sense or not...don't know
        socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("<multicast ip here>"));

        while (true) {
            byte ab[] = new byte[583];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(ab, ab.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println("Got packet " + Arrays.toString(ab));
        }
    }
}
```

This program is not able to capture the packets from given multicast group and port.

For testing, I created one MulticastSockerServer which will send data on one multicast group and port.

**sender -**

```
public class MulticastServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("<multicast group ip>");
        final int port = <port number>;

        try {
            MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(9000);
            //socket.setInterface(InetAddress.getByName("<local interface ip address>"));
            socket.joinGroup(group);

            byte[] bt = new byte[100];
            byte index = 0;
            while (true) {
                Arrays.fill(bt, (byte) index++);
                socket.send(new DatagramPacket(bt, 100, group, port));
                System.out.println("sent 100 bytes");
                Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this two program then it will works as I expected, data get captured at receiver side. Then why the receiver only is not able to capture data from different multicast group ip and port?

Any suggestions will be appropriated.

Comment: Just to be sure: that tcpdump call - basically you did an experiment on that system you are running the java code to make sure that you can actually connect to the multicast server? To prevent to be blocked by a firewall for example?

Comment: @GhostCat- I already checked about firewall status and it is not running currently. My java sender and receiver works fine but still unable to capture data from servers multicast group ip and port

Comment: Your Java client only displays UDP multicast datagrams, but your tcpdump command displays any type of multicast datagrams, not only UDP ones => are you sure there are UDP multicast datagrams on your local network? Another question: do you have multiple interfaces on your host?

Comment: BTW the sender doesn't need to use a `MulticastSocket` or join the group. Only the receiver does. Sender can just use a `DatagramSocket`.

Answer (score 1):

I got clarity and I found why java client not getting data. Actually the tcpdump command is -

```
tcpdump -i <interface name> dst <multicast ip>
```

This command will capture any packets (i.e. No matter it is UDP or PGM) which has destination address is given by command (multicast ip).

Java Client will only capture UDP Packets not PGM Packets. On my local network, only PGM packets are available so tcpdump command will give us data but Java client will not receive any data.

If you want to capture PGM Packets then you need to use one of the below -

1. Use **JnetPcap** library to capture/read any (i.e. UDP or PGM) packets.
2. Use **Javapgm** library to capture pgm packets only.
3. Use **dumpcap** to capture packets and store it in a pcap file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note: PGM has been 'experimental' since 2001 and is still not an IETF standard.